# Efficient way of searching String Array in Hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have following hashmap with a string array:

```
public static HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
map.put("calculus",new String[] {"math","logic"});
map.put("chemisty",new String[] {"ions","electrons"});
map.put("biology",new String[] {"life","bacteria"});
```

I have a string which I want to search in the String arrays in the Hashmap. My code is:

```
public String findFn(String myString) {

    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();

        for(String s : entry.getValue()) {
            if(s.contains(myString)) {
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
```

This would effectively iterate through entire hashmap values until the match is found. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Not with your current data structure.

Comment: Maybe maintain a reverse map with `arrayElement -> key` (if this search happens very often)

Comment: If you want efficient searching, a hashmap of plain arrays is a terrible choice. Then again, if this is all the data you have, the idea of needing efficient searching seems... irrelevant? Just maintain a parallel reverse lookup, which given your data looks like it can just be a string:string map. Then do your lookups in O(1)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have thousands of records in the hashmap. Then what is the efficient data structure for this? A piece of code would help :)

Comment: What if the value is in multiple entries? I don't know what the data will be, but I guess that for example DNA could be in both chemistry and biology.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj A value will not be in multiple entries

Comment: ... why do you have thousands of records in the hashmap? At that point, why on earth are you not storing your data in... you know... a database? (e.g. "please update your post to explain what you're actually doing, so that we don't end up several layers deep into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)")

Answer (score 3):

With your current data structure, this is the best you can do. If you need to do this often, you should build another Hashmap with the reverse relationship where the "topic" is the key and the "course" is the value.

Comment: @user5155835 `map.put("math", "calculus");`

Answer (score 0):

If the number of entries in the `HashMap` will be low and number of items in the values will be high, I would go with just a slight modification of your code replacing arrays with HashSets:

```
public static HashMap<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("calculus", new HashSet());
map.get("calculus").add("math");
...

public String findFn(String myString) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {           
        for(String s : entry.getValue()) {
            if(s.contains(myString)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `HashSet.contains()` has constant-time performance so the code will iterate only on the number of classifiers.